# Check if all objects in an NSArray are identical

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray

I have searched this on the internet, but have found no solution...

Here is what I want:

Say I have an `NSArray` with three objects. These three objects are:

```
{

@"Hi",
@"Hi",
@"Hi"

 }
```

In this case the array contains three strings, which are all equal.

I want to testify for this, I want to create an `NSArray` category `BOOL`method that loops through all the objects and returns `YES` if they are all identical. Here is an example:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Object", @"Object", @"Object", nil];

if ([array allObjectsAreIdentical /* method I would have to create */) {

     NSLog(@"All objects in this array are identical");
}
```

I am pretty sure that there is no built in method for this, and also I would prefer not to take the tedious route and manually compare each object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:array];
if ([set count] == 0) {
     // array is empty. Does that count as identical ?
} else if ([set count] == 1) {
     // all objects in array are identical
} else {
     // there are different objects
}
```

**EDIT:** Written as `NSArray` category method this would be

```
-(BOOL) allObjectsAreIdentical
{
    NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:self];
    return ([set count] <= 1);
}
```

*Note:* You should be aware that this solution (even if it might *look* elegant) compares more objects in the array than necessary. Therefore, if performance is an issue, you better go with other solutions, e.g. the one proposed by @dieworld.

Comment: It will do more work - because you asked it to create a set of all distinguishable items of the array - so it must loop through ALL of the items in the array. Whereas to find if all items are identical - you can break as soon as you find two that are not identical. However, this looks so nice and elegant...

Answer (score 5):

More cheap (I hope) way in terms of resources and time:

```
- (BOOL) allObjectsAreIdentical
{
    if (self.count < 2) return YES;
    for (int i = 0; i < self.count - 1; i++) {
        if (![[self objectAtIndex: i] isEqual: [self lastObject]]) return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Assuming one object is always equal to itself and zero objects are also equal.

Comment: You are right, your solution requires less compare operations than mine (+1).

Comment: There is small bug, loop should start from i=1, not 0.

Comment: actually, there should be `i` instead of `i - 1` in `objectAtIndex`. updated my answer.

Comment: @johnpatrickmorgan, it does not actually compares last object with itself. Assume we have, say, 5 objects (indices 0, 1, 2, 3, 4). Then condition will be "i < 4", and the last iteration will compare lastObject with object at index "i = 3", and the last object has index 4.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion to be a bit faster and avoid an exception being thrown when the array is empty. Should be a category of NSArray to be generally usable. No check unless at least two elements. Check object pointers before calling isEqual:, assuming that often equal objects are actually the same object.

```
@interface NSArray (objectsAreIdentical)
- (BOOL)allObjectsAreIdentical;
@end

@implementation NSArray (objectsAreIdentical)

- (BOOL)allObjectsAreIdentical
{
    BOOL result = YES;
    if (self.count >= 2)
    {
        id firstObject = self [0];
        for (id object in self)
        {
            if (firstObject != object && ! [firstObject isEqual:object])
            {
                result = NO;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
@end
```

Comment: This was a while ago, but nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be (just to put it down here.. just in case):

```
- (BOOL)allObjectsAreIdenticalInArray:(NSArray *)mArray
{
    if(!mArray || ![mArray count])
    {
        return YES;//if it is empty
    }

    NSString *mTestString = [mArray objectAtIndex:0];

    for(NSString *mString in mArray)
    {
        if(![mTestString isEqalToString:mString])
        {
            return NO; //we found atleast one who isnt.
        }
    }

    return YES; //everything checks out - they all are the same.
}
```

But I would go with **Martin R** solution.

Comment: This will work for NSString objects in array, but NSArray can contain any object type.

Comment: You compare the first array element with itself, therefore the result will always be NO for a non-empty array.

Comment: @Martin R  You sure about that?  Firstly I take first object and then compare all objects to first value. Including first. If they DONT match = then it returns NO.

Comment: @Enrique Yes, You are right, but I am responding to example mention in question, which contains only strings.

Comment: @GuntisTreulands: You are right, my comment was wrong, I am sorry.

Comment: This will throw an exception if the array is empty.